# How does this Access join query work in Teradata?

Tags: join, inner-join, teradata, correlated-subquery

I'm trying to determine the equivalent version of this query in Teradata. The main problem I'm experiencing is trying to figure out a way to join the same column twice using two different keys ( package_unit_id and retail_unit_id). In Access, I was able to assign an alias that allowed me to select the tbleDIRGA_ItemUnit.Unit_Name column twice. How does that work in Teradata? Let me know if I'm not being clear.

**In Microsoft Access:**

```
SELECT 

    tblDIRGA_Item.SubTeam_No, 
    tblDIRGA_ItemIdentifier.Identifier, 
    tblDIRGA_ItemUnit.Unit_Name AS PackUOM,
    tblDIRGA_ItemUnit_1.Unit_Name AS RetailUOM

FROM (((tblDIRGA_ItemIdentifier AS tblDIRGA_ItemIdentifier_1 

INNER JOIN tblDIRGA_Item 
ON tblDIRGA_ItemIdentifier.Item_Key = tblDIRGA_Item.Item_Key)

INNER JOIN tblDIRGA_ItemUnit 
ON tblDIRGA_Item.Package_Unit_ID = tblDIRGA_ItemUnit.Unit_ID) 

INNER JOIN tblDIRGA_ItemUnit AS tblDIRGA_ItemUnit_1 
ON tblDIRGA_Item.Retail_Unit_ID = tblDIRGA_ItemUnit_1.Unit_ID)
```

**In Teradata:**

In Teradata I am trying to select unit_name from the ir_item_unit_v table twice using two different keys (package_unit_id) and (retail_unit_id). How does this work like in Access above?

```
SELECT

    st.subteam_no
    ik.identifier
    **u.unit_name AS RetailUOM,**
    **uu.unit_name AS PackUOM**

FROM DRG_R.IR_PRICE_V ip

    JOIN ir_item_identifier_v ik
    ON ip.region = ik.region 
    AND ik.item_key = ip.item_key 

    JOIN ir_item_v i 
    ON ip.region = i.region
    AND i.item_key = ip.item_key 

    **JOIN ir_item_unit_v u AS ir_item_unit_1_v uu
    ON i.package_unit_id=u.unit_id
    AND i.region=u.region**

    **JOIN ir_item_unit_v u
    ON i.retail_unit_id=u.unit_id
    AND i.region=u.region**
```

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 3):

It works exactly the same in Teradata, assign different aliases:

```
SELECT
   st.subteam_no
   ik.identifier,
   u.unit_name AS RetailUOM,
   uu.unit_name AS PackUOM
FROM DRG_R.IR_PRICE_V ip

JOIN ir_item_identifier_v AS ik
ON ip.region = ik.region 
AND ik.item_key = ip.item_key 

JOIN ir_item_v AS i 
ON ip.region = i.region
AND i.item_key = ip.item_key 

JOIN ir_item_unit_v AS u
ON i.package_unit_id=u.unit_id
AND i.region=u.region

JOIN ir_item_unit_v AS uu
ON i.retail_unit_id=uu.unit_id
AND i.region=uu.region
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to give the table two different aliases. Maybe u1 and u2? Just make sure you properly reference the aliases in your select and join.

Comment: I'm confused about the syntax in Teradata for using the two different aliases

Comment: JOIN ir_item_unit_v u1
ON i.package_unit_id=u1.unit_id
AND i.region=u1.region

JOIN ir_item_unit_v u2  ON i.retail_unit_id=u2.unit_id
AND i.region=u2.region

Comment: SELECT

    st.subteam_no,
    ik.identifier,
    u.unit_name AS RetailUOM,
    uu.unit_name AS PackUOM
    FROM DRG_R.IR_PRICE_V ip

    JOIN ir_item_identifier_v ik
    ON ip.region = ik.region 
    AND ik.item_key = ip.item_key 

    JOIN ir_item_v i 
    ON ip.region = i.region
    AND i.item_key = ip.item_key 

   JOIN ir_item_unit_v  uu
    ON i.package_unit_id=uu.unit_id
    AND i.region=uu.region

    JOIN ir_item_unit_v u
    ON i.retail_unit_id=u.unit_id
   AND i.region=u.region